# Can't include wp-load.php in cron job with curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, cron

I have a page with this code called by cron and nothing happens.
If I call the page from the browser it works and I see the message "wp-load.php is included"

```
if( file_exists("wp-load.php") ){
    if( is_readable("wp-load.php")) {
        echo "wp-load.php is readable";
        if( include("wp-load.php")){ 
            echo "wp-load.php is included."; 
        }
    }

}
```

If I remove these lines then it works by cron and I see the message "wp-load.php is readable":

```
if( include("wp-load.php")){ 
            echo "wp-load.php is included."; 
        }
```

If I modify the code by including another file (es TEST.php) it works by cron and I see the message "TEST.php is included:

```
if( file_exists("wp-load.php") ){
    if( is_readable("wp-load.php")) {
        echo "wp-load.php is readable";
        if( include("TEST.php")){ 
            echo "TEST.php is included."; 
        }
    }

}
```

Why?
The page is called from cron with GET request via web client (http)
From the logs the cron runs correctly

Comment: If you were to run this via CLI, then different settings for include_path or similar could make a difference - but if you are executing this by making an HTTP request for the script URL, then this isn’t really explainable, that should behave the same way as in a normal browser then.

Comment: “Nothing happens” smells like a possible PHP error, is error reporting turned on for both PHP and WordPress? Also, what do you expect to happen? Cron is a background task so there’s no visual, does this do other work?

Comment: I do a debug in a text file. From the browser I read the messages from CRON nothing happens. Only if I remove include (wp-load.php) is the debug file written from Cron

Comment: If there was a php error then even from the browser it would not work